# Excel to PDF conversion in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, excel, csv, pdf

It is asked to me to do a small excel to pdf conversion.

Let me describe what is exactly to be done.
in excel file there are list of companies which looks like this...
[image]

and to retrieve a company name turn into this in PDF format, like this...

[image]

I am thinking to follow a path...

1-using php and js I will get excel file with "input type=file"

2-using [pdf reader php script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader)  I will retrieve the data required.

After this I am confusing...

3-I can retrieve data by searching and parsing a company name( for example getting an input: "company:A") till next keyword of "company" for all columns

or should I put all data from excel into CSV file and do the parsing part there???

4- after that, I  am thinking to use, one of the [tcpdf](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php) example methodologies however here comes another confusing point for me... because I don't know which type of output should get from excel or csv and load into pdf converter method.

An enlightening path would be appreciated since I am confused

Regards

Comment: The [PHPExcel library](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) has this functionality (reading CSV and writing PDF)without any need for you to write it yourself.... you even have a choice of which PDF renderer you want to use (mPDF, tcPDF or DomPDF)

Comment: ok, I didnt know thanks... I will play around with it... if I stuck on a point I might re-ask :) @MarkBaker

Answer (score 0):

Build your Data on HTML format first then if you got the correct display on html then you can now convert it to a PDF file.